# consume a php soap service from C#

Tags: c#, soap-client

I have made a simple web service

wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions name='mysum' >

<wsdl:types>
 <xsd:schema 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:tns="http://www.my-uni-project.info/joomla/components/com_jv_vm_soa/"
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="mysum"
   targetNamespace="http://www.my-uni-project.info/joomla/components/com_jv_vm_soa/"
   xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

   <xsd:complexType name="mysumRequest">
    <xsd:all>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="n1" type="xsd:int"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="n2" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:all>
   </xsd:complexType>   

   <xsd:element name="mysumResponse" type="xsd:int"/>
  </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>

 <wsdl:message name="mysumRequest">
   <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:mysumRequest" />
 </wsdl:message> 
 <wsdl:message name="mysumResponse">
   <wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:mysumResponse" />
 </wsdl:message> 


 <wsdl:portType name="mysum">
  <wsdl:operation name="mysum">
   <wsdl:input message="tns:mysumRequest"/>
   <wsdl:output message="tns:mysumResponse"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:portType> 

 <wsdl:binding name="mysumSOAP" type="tns:mysum">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <wsdl:operation name="mysum">
   <soap:operation soapAction="mysum" />
   <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:binding> 

 <wsdl:service name="mysum">
  <wsdl:port name="mysumSOAP" binding="tns:mysumSOAP">
    <soap:address location="http://www.my-uni-
    project.info/joomla/components/com_jv_vm_soa/mysum.php" />
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

the service:

function mysum($parameters) {

$result =  $parameters->item[0]->value + $parameters->item[1]->value;
  return $result  ;
 }

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache 
 $server = new SoapServer("mysum.wsdl"); 
 $server->addFunction("mysum"); 
 $server->handle();

that I can access from a php client:

`$client = new SoapClient("http://www.my-uni-
     project.info/joomla/components/com_jv_vm_soa/mysum.wsdl"); 
    $params = array('n1' => '4', 'n2' => '8');`

```
try { 
  $result = $client->__soapCall('mysum', array('parameters' => $params));
```

echo $result; 
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) { 
      echo $exception;
     }

I tried to create a C# client so first I created a service reference "mysum", then on the form I added a button and a label and I added the following code for the button

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mysum s = new mysum();
        label1.Text = "" + s.mysum(2, 3);                
    }
```

Whe I run it I get this error:

```
Error 5 The type or namespace name 'mysum' could not be found (are you 
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The service is online

Thank you in advanced
John

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can determine if you can resolve the problem using a directive by right-clicking on the object in question, in this case mysum, and seeing if you can 'Resolve Using ' where  is the name of your directive.

Comment: Looking more into it I found that there is a problem with the wsdl and visual studio can not generate the proxy class...  Can anyone spot it?

Comment: Tried to run wsdl.exe on it, and sure enough I get: "Error: There is an error in XML document (1, 2).
  - 'wsdl' is an undeclared namespace. Line 1, position 2."

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are adding the service as a service reference instead of web service reference.

To add a web service reference

1. Add service reference
2. Hit the **Advanced** button on the window
3. Hit **Add Web Reference**
4. Enter the service url

Also,

Make sure you have added the System.Web.Services namespace reference in your project.

Hope it helps.